# Find slant height of liquid inside a tilted cylindrical beaker

Tags: integration

A beaker of radius *R* tilted at a angle $ \theta $ and has a volume *V*, For understanding the problem please see the linked image.

Now what I have tried myself:-

I tried 3 different attempts in order to solve the problem but I have failed, Stuck in a Equation that can't be further solved.

attempt 1:-

I first divided the figure into two symmetric halves and considered a infinitesimally right-triangular sheet and tried to integrate it through and got a equation but it didn't solved to the considered answer.

attempt 2:-

This time I tried with a rectangular sheet with length x and height xtan$ \theta $ with dx width but this too end up with a weird equation.

attempt 3:-

With same rectangular sheet but different method and same result failed :=-(

I am a web developer and I use equations to build HTML5 canvas animation and this equation would be used in a liquid graphic, If you could help me please.

IMAGE:-[Refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BVv4.png)

Comment: The image makes no sense. I would have thought the surface of the liquid would be horizontal, and for a height I would imagine a vertical distance rather than whatever that not quite horizontal arrow indicates.
That said, if you are doing essentially a 2D graphic, you might as well cheat by illustrating the liquid using a constant area, as if the beaker had a square instead of a circular base.

Comment: What if the cylinder is more than half full? Also, the tilt angle is usually the angle between the surface and the side of cylinder.